# Getting started with OpenCV 2.4 and MinGW on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, mingw

How do I install OpenCV 2.4 and compile my code with MinGW?

Comment: Wow, 11 downvotes and 30 upvotes. I think this is a 'too broad question' versus 'this helped me a lot'.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**1. Installing OpenCV 2.4.3**

First, get [OpenCV 2.4.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) from sourceforge.net. Its a self-file-extracting so just double click the file to start installation. Install it in a directory, say *`C:\`*.

[image: OpenCV self-extracting]

Wait until all files get extracted. It will create a new 
directory *`C:\opencv`* which contains OpenCV header files, libraries, code samples, etc.

Now you need to add *`C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin`* directory to your system PATH. This directory contains OpenCV DLLs which is required for running your code.

Open **Control Panel** → **System** → **Advanced system settings** → **Advanced Tab** → **Environment variables...**

You will see a window like shown below:

[image: Add OpenCV DLL directory to system path]

On the System Variables section,
select **Path** (1), click **Edit...** (2), add *`C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin`* (3) then click **Ok**.

This will completes the OpenCV 2.4.3 installation on your computer.

---

**2. Installing MinGW compiler suite**

I highly recommend you to use gcc (GNU Compiler Collection) for compiling your code. gcc is the compiler suite widely available in Linux systems and MinGW is the native port for Windows.

Download the [MinGW installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) from Sourceforge.net and double click to start installation. Just follow the wizard and select the directory to be installed, say *`C:\MinGW`*.

[image: Select directory in MinGW installation]

Select "C Compiler" and "C++ Compiler" to be installed.

[image: Select components to be installed]

The installer will download some packages from the internet so you have to wait for a while. After the installation finished, add *`C:\MinGW\bin`* to your system path using the steps described before.

[image: Add MinGW bin directory to system path]

To test if your MinGW installation is success, open a command-line box and type: `gcc`. If everything is ok, it will display this message:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

This completes the MinGW installation, now is the time to write your "Hello, World!" program.

---

**3. Write a sample code**

Open your text editor and type the code below and save the file to `loadimg.cpp`.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat im = imread(argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "lena.jpg", 1);
  if (im.empty())
  {
    cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  imshow("image", im);
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Put `lena.jpg` or any image you like in the same directory with the file above. Open a command-line box and compile the code above by typing:

```
g++ -I"C:\opencv\build\include" -L"C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" loadimg.cpp -lopencv_core243 -lopencv_highgui243 -o loadimg
```

If it compiles successfully, it will create an executable named `loadimg.exe`.

Type:

```
loadimg
```

To execute the program. Result:

[image: The result of your first OpenCV program]

---

**4. Where to go from here?**

Now that your OpenCV environment is ready, what's next?

1. Go to the samples dir → *`C:\opencv\samples\cpp`*.
2. Read and compile some code.
3. Write your own code.

Comment: I followed your instructions and got loadimg.exe to build but it crashes straight away when I try to execute it -- exception code=c0000005 and faulting module=libstdc++-6.dll. Running on gdb in eclipse shows a seg fault in libstdc++ . Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug http://answers.opencv.org/question/172/segfault-in-opencv-242-and-mingw-on-winxp/?answer=175#post-id-175

Comment: @volting I face the similar kinda issue.. Have u solved it? Any solution for this?

Comment: @user1317084 - Nope.. I moved developement to linux for other reasons. But I believe that you can solve this by getting the latest version from the repo and building it from source..

Comment: @volting check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005/17402441#17402441

Comment: @user1317084 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005/17402441#17402441

Comment: If your program CRASHES with a 0000005 error, you should compile the library by yourself, USE NENAD BULATOVIC ANSWER wich is below, after that it should WORK JUST FINE

Comment: Apparently, mingw binaries are no longer included. Check http://grauonline.de/wordpress/?page_id=449 for a description on how to compile OpenCV.

Answer (score 21):

The instructions in @bsdnoobz answer are indeed helpful, but didn't get OpenCV to work on my system.

Apparently I needed to compile the library myself in order to get it to work, and not count on the pre-built binaries (which caused my programs to crash, probably due to incompatibility with my system).

I did get it to work, and wrote a comprehensive guide for **[compiling and installing OpenCV, and configuring Netbeans to work with it.](http://eyalarubas.com/opencv-installation-on-windows-netbeans-mingw.html)**

For completeness, it is also provided below.

---

When I first started using OpenCV, I encountered two major difficulties:

1. Getting my programs NOT to crash immediately.
2. Making Netbeans play nice, and especially getting timehe debugger to work.

I read many tutorials and "how-to" articles, but none was really comprehensive
and thorough. Eventually I succeeded in setting up the environment; and after a
while of using this (great) library, I decided to write this small tutorial,
which will hopefully help others.

The are three parts to this tutorial:

1. Compiling and installing OpenCV.
2. Configuring Netbeans.
3. An example program.

**The environment I use is**:
Windows 7, OpenCV 2.4.0, Netbeans 7 and MinGW 3.20 (with compiler gcc 4.6.2).

**Assumptions**:
You already have MinGW and Netbeans installed on your system.

### Compiling and installing OpenCV

When downloading OpenCV, the archive actually already contains pre-built
binaries (compiled libraries and DLL's) in the 'build' folder. At first, I
tried using those binaries, assuming somebody had already done the job of
compiling for me. That didn't work.

**Eventually I figured I have to compile the entire library on my own system in
order for it to work properly.**

Luckily, the compilation process is rather easy, thanks to CMake.  CMake
(stands for Cross-platform Make) is a tool which generates makefiles specific
to your compiler and platform. We will use CMake in order to configure our
building and compilation settings, generate a 'makefile', and then compile the
library.

The steps are:

1. Download [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and install it (in the installation wizard choose to add
   CMake to the system PATH).
2. Download the 'release' version of [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).
3. Extract the archive to a directory of your choice. I will be using
   `c:/opencv/`.
4. Launch CMake GUI.

   1. Browse for the source directory `c:/opencv/`.
   2. Choose where to build the binaries. I chose `c:/opencv/release`.
      [image: CMake Configuration - 1]
   3. Click 'Configure'. In the screen that opens choose the generator
      according to your compiler. In our case it's 'MinGW Makefiles'.
      [image: CMake Configuration - 2]
   4. Wait for everything to load, afterwards you will see this screen:
      [image: CMake Configuration - 3]
   5. Change the settings if you want, or leave the defaults. When you're
      done, press 'Configure' again. You should see 'Configuration done' at
      the log window, and the red background should disappear from all the
      cells.
      [image: CMake Configuration - 4]
   6. At this point CMake is ready to generate the makefile with which we will
      compile OpenCV with our compiler. Click 'Generate' and wait for the
      makefile to be generated. When the process is finished you should see
      'Generating done'. From this point we will no longer need CMake.
5. Open MinGW shell (The following steps can also be done from Windows' command
   prompt).

   1. Enter the directory `c:/opencv/release/`.
   2. Type `mingw32-make` and press enter. This should start the compilation
      process.
      [image: MinGW Make]
      [image: MinGW Make - Compilation]
   3. When the compilation is done OpenCV's binaries are ready to be used.
   4. For convenience, **we should add the directory `C:/opencv/release/bin`
      to the system PATH**. This will make sure our programs can find the
      needed DLL's to run.

### Configuring Netbeans

Netbeans should be told where to find the header files and the compiled
libraries (which were created in the previous section).

The header files are needed for two reasons: for compilation and for code
completion. The compiled libraries are needed for the linking stage.

Note: In order for debugging to work, the OpenCV DLL's should be available,
which is why we added the directory which contains them to the system PATH
(previous section, step 5.4).

First, you should verify that Netbeans is configured correctly to work with
MinGW. Please see the screenshot below and verify your settings are correct
(considering paths changes according to your own installation). **Also note**
that the `make` command should be from msys and **not** from Cygwin.

[image: Netbeans MinGW Configuration]

Next, for each new project you create in Netbeans, you should define the
include path (the directory which contains the header files), the libraries
path and the specific libraries you intend to use.  Right-click the project
name in the 'projects' pane, and choose 'properties'.  Add the include path
(modify the path according to your own installation):

[image: Netbeans Project Include Path]

Add the libraries path:

[image: Netbeans Libraries Path]

Add the specific libraries you intend to use. These libraries will be
dynamically linked to your program in the linking stage. Usually you will need
the `core` library plus any other libraries according to the specific needs of
your program.

[image: Netbeans Include Libraries]

That's it, you are now ready to use OpenCV!

### Summary

Here are the general steps you need to complete in order to install OpenCV and
use it with Netbeans:

1. Compile OpenCV with your compiler.
2. Add the directory which contains the DLL's to your system PATH (in our case:
   c:/opencv/release/bin).
3. Add the directory which contains the header files to your project's include
   path (in our case: c:/opencv/build/include).
4. Add the directory which contains the compiled libraries to you project's
   libraries path (in our case: c:/opencv/release/lib).
5. Add the specific libraries you need to be linked with your project (for
   example: libopencv_core240.dll.a).

### Example - "Hello World" with OpenCV

Here is a small example program which draws the text "Hello World : )" on a GUI
window. You can use it to check that your installation works correctly. After
compiling and running the program, you should see the following window:

[image: OpenCV Hello World]

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //create a gui window:
    namedWindow("Output",1);

    //initialize a 120X350 matrix of black pixels:
    Mat output = Mat::zeros( 120, 350, CV_8UC3 );

    //write text on the matrix:
    putText(output,
            "Hello World :)",
            cvPoint(15,70),
            FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
            3,
            cvScalar(0,255,0),
            4);

    //display the image:
    imshow("Output", output);

    //wait for the user to press any key:
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This proved really helpful coz i never wanted to use visual studio for compiling opencv . I feel comfortable with Eclipse cdt and did not wanted to fill my hard disk with not so important visual studio . +1

Comment: @RahulVerma You are right, I also had to compile binaries for myself. Described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005/17402441#17402441

Comment: I get a __403 Forbidden__ when accessing the links in your post. Maybe editing your answer and adding the tutorial _into_ it, would be a better idea?

Answer (score 13):

This isn't working for me. I spent few days following every single tutorial I found on net and finally i compiled my own binaries. Everyting is described here: [OpenVC 2.4.5, eclipse CDT Juno, MinGW error 0xc0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005/17402441#17402441)

After many trials and errors I decided to follow [this](http://www.argong.com/docs/how-to-OpenCV-2.2.0.pdf) tutorial and to compile my own binaries as it seems that too many people are complaining that precompiled binaries are NOT working for them. Eclipse CDT Juno was already installed.

My procedure was as follows:

1. Download and install MinGW and add to the system PATH with
   c:/mingw/bin
2. Download cmake from http://www.cmake.org and install it
3. Download OpenCV2.4.5 Windows version
4. Install/unzip Opencv to C:\OpenCV245PC\ (README,index.rst and CMakeLists.txt are there with all subfolders)
5. Run CMake GUI tool, then
6. Choose C:\OpenCV245PC\ as source
7. Choose the destination, C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86  where to build the binaries
8. Press Configure button, choose MinGW Makefiles as the generator. There are some red highlights in the window, choose options as you need.
9. Press the Configure button **again**. Configuring is now done.
10. Press the Generate button.
11. Exit the program when the generating is done.
12. Exit the Cmake program.
13. Run the command line mode (cmd.exe) and go to the destination
     directory C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86
14. Type "mingw32-make". You will see a progress of building
     binaries. If the command is not found, you must make sure that the
     system PATH is added with c:/mingw/bin. The build continues
     according the chosen options to a completion.
15. In Windows system PATH (My Computer > Right button click >
     Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > Path) add the
     destination's bin directory, C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86\bin
16. RESTART COMPUTER
17. Go to the Eclipse CDT IDE, create a C++ program using the sample OpenCV code (You can use code from top of this topic).
18. Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes, and add
    the source OpenCV folder "C:\OpenCV245PC\build\include"
19. Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries, and add to the **Libraries (-l)** ONE BY ONE (this could vary from project to project, you can add all of them if you like or some of them just the ones that you need for your project): opencv_calib3d245 opencv_contrib245 opencv_core245 opencv_features2d245 opencv_flann245 opencv_gpu245 opencv_highgui245 opencv_imgproc245 opencv_legacy245 opencv_ml245 opencv_nonfree245 opencv_objdetect245 opencv_photo245 opencv_stitching245 opencv_video245 opencv_videostab245
20. Add the built OpenCV library folder,  "C:\OpenCV245MinGW\x86\lib" to **Library search path (-L)**.

You can use this code to test your setup:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("c:/lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to put image to the C:/ (or wherever you might find suitable, just be sure that eclipse have read acess.

Comment: While executing mingw32-make on step 15 you received an error "ACCESS IS DENIED"? disable any antivirus or other software that might be locking files

Comment: Where did you get that I had "ACCESS IS DENIED" on step 15? I never had such problem (multiple installations on different computers) with procedure I described above, and I never disabled Antivirus. Also, I think you speak about step 14 not 15.

Comment: My Bad, step 14, i received this error twice in Win7 64bits, using AVG and Windows Security Essentials, i dont remember exactly wich file was throwing the error, but it was about 32% of compilation proccess, using CMake 2.8, after disabling both antivirus it finished with no errors

Comment: I am also using Win7 64bits and AVG but not using Windows Security Essentials. On the other hand, AVG on several occasions blocked my OpenCV C++ compiled programs, the ones that were intensely writing image frames on disk - so, yes, Antivirus software could definitely interfere...

Answer (score 3):

If you installed opencv 2.4.2 then you need to change the `-lopencv_core240` to `-lopencv_core242`

I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 64bits it´s works:

1. Download [opencv-3.0 (beta)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0.0-rc1/opencv-3.0.0-rc1.exe/download), [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/) (command line tool);
2. Add above respective bin folder to PATH var;
3. Create an folder "release" (could be any name) into ;
4. Into created folder, open prompt terminal and exec the below commands;
5. Copy and Past this command

   `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mingw32-g++.exe -D WITH_IPP=OFF MAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ..\`
6. Execute this command `mingw32-make`
7. Execute this command `mingw32-make install`

**DONE**

Answer (score 1):

I used the instructions in this step-by-step and it worked.

http://nenadbulatovic.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/configuring-opencv-245-eclipse-cdt-juno.html

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Nenad Bulatovic one has to be careful while adding libraries(19th step). one should not add any trailing spaces while adding each library line by line. otherwise mingw goes haywire.