# Installing OpenCV2.4.1 on windows 7 x64 - Mingw & codeblocks

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw, codeblocks

Installing OpenCV2.4.1 on windows 7 x64 - Mingw & codeblocks

Hi, 
I followed this tutorial

[Getting started with OpenCV 2.4 and MinGW on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7)

I configured the same except instead of x86, i put x64.

This is the example

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat im = imread(argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "lena.jpg", 1);
if (im.empty())
{
cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
return -1;
}

imshow("image", im);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

when i compile main.cpp

**C:\Users\rgap\Desktop>g++ -I"C:\opencv\build\include" -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib" main.cpp -lope 
ncv_core241 -lopencv_highgui241 -o main**

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `cv::imread(
std::string const&, int)'
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `cv::_InputA
rray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(
std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `cv::waitKe
y(int)'
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[cv::Mat::~Mat()]+0x2b): und
efined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\Users\rgap\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDgmPAT.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0
x3c): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

Is this a bug? :(

thanks :)

Comment: it seems you have a space in `-lope ncv_core241`

Comment: And make sure you're using 64 bit version of MinGW

Comment: Im using 64 bit version, i think is a problem of mingw version

Comment: did u manage to fix this?

Comment: Although it's for eclipse you might want to check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393311/openvc-2-4-5-eclipse-cdt-juno-mingw-error-0xc0000005/17402441#17402441