# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000be)

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

I installed OpenCV 2.4.0 in codeblocks IDE with help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876052/how-to-compile-a-program-using-opencv-2-4-3-with-codeblocks) in my windows 32bit pc. I follow the all the steps properly I think.

when I run the following code it works well:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"Hello"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

But when i run this code it shows that ***The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000be)***

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cv::Mat im = cv::imread("m.jpg");

    if (im.empty())
    {
        cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout<<"image is showing.......\n";

    cv::imshow("image", im);

   // waitKey(0);

   cout<<"Hello"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any other configuration for working well with opencv in codeblocks.

I googled and find that it is not a problem of configuring rather problem of windows. I stuck many hours of googling and find nothing helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to compile openCV with the same compiler you're using to compile the program.  It looks like someone found a solution to the same problem here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/30343/application-unable-to-start-correctly/