# installing OpenCV with Code::Blocks / CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, codeblocks

I am fairly new to C++ in general (though I am getting used to the basics), but now I am trying to add OpenCV to my projects to access some of the basic image processing features. I have read the documentation so I have a pretty good idea where to start, but I am really stuck with the installation.

I am working with Code::Blocks 16.01, and I have downloaded both CMake 3.4.3 and OpenCV 3.0.0 and 3.1.0. OpenCV has been extracted to "c:\opencv", and I have attempted to finish the build with CMake (using the directions from the OpenCV documentation as well as from several older posts from this site). I am selecting "Codeblocks - MinGW Makefiles" from the list of generators, though I have selected from all of the "Codeblocks" options at one point or another.

Anyway, whenever I try to configure or generate I receive the following error: "The program can't start because libintl-8.dll is missing from your computer." So yeah, I am stuck.

It is worth noting that many, if not all, of the posts I have found refer to a directory named "\x86\mingw\lib", however I cannot find "mingw" in any of the OpenCV downloads (and the most recent is missing "x86" as well) - so none of these posts have been particularly useful to me (for example):

[How to compile a program using OpenCV 2.4.3 with Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876052/how-to-compile-a-program-using-opencv-2-4-3-with-codeblocks)

Comment: there are no more prebuild mingw libs, you have to build them from src using cmake

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I sort of figured that they left mingw out for a reason. It really seems like my problem is with this missing "libintl-8.dll" file when I try to build using CMake. I have followed this video precisely - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9IBIEDex18 - and I get the same error when I go to configure. It is the same with every other tutorial I have followed. I have no idea what that error means or how to begin solving it.

Comment: As a follow-up: I have just tried testing the build with several of the other generator options, including Visual Studio 2015, and I always get the same error. When I check "CMakeError.log" I get several similar entries:Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1

Comment: hmm, last time i trid i explicitely had to specify the cxx and c compiler and the mingwmake tool

Answer (score 0):

Put the path to all the MinGW dll files in your pc's path variable.  Check your Code::Blocks installation directory ( C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin ) if it does not exist, you'd have to download and install MinGW separately. You'd have to add the MinGW .dll files to the path environment.