# Configuring OpenCV 2.4.4 for Code Blocks - libopencv_core244.dll was not found

Tags: opencv, codeblocks, configure

I have been trying to configure OpenCV 2.4.4 for CodeBlocks for quite some time now but even though I follow online guides somehow I can't do it and I am slowly getting desperate. I tried to do what Mr. bsdnoobz said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7) topic, but it still does not work.
Here's what I've done so far:

- I have installed OpenCV 2.4.4 and MinGW successfully:

  > C:\Users\Max\gcc
  >   gcc: fatal error: no input files
  >   compilation terminated
- I have added to Path this:

  > D:\OpenCV\build\x86\mingw\bin;C:\MinGW\bin; D:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\bin
- In Code Blocks i set up everything like this:

Yet i get the following error:

> could not start the program because libopencv_core244.dll is not found

and even though i tried heavily i cant fix it. Hope somebody can help me!

Comment: I can't add more than two links in my post so here are the links to the photos of how i set up everything: http://postimg.org/image/kw8zb1243/
http://postimg.org/image/62r0zkb41/
http://postimg.org/image/3y6h67yvd/
http://postimg.org/image/bacueuuft/

Comment: You are saying to install OpenCV successfully, but you screenshot shows GCC error and in general is unrelated. Try re-installing OpenCV and follow any errors that appear.

Comment: But in the link I posted at the top Mr. bsdnoobz posted: "To test if your MinGW installation is success, open a command-line box and type: gcc. If everything is ok, it will display this message:

gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated" then it means that the installation was successfull.

Comment: Why would my post get a vote down if I thoroughly described my problem (which is, in my opinion, very serious) and politely asked for help?

Comment: Message indicates that MinGW was installed successfully, and MinGW is nothing more than GNU compiler collection. It does nothing with OpenCV. CodeBlocks claims that it can't find OpenCV libraries in PATH. If you are sure that OpenCV is installed successfully too, check your path ("D:\OpenCV\build\x86\mingw\bin") for these DLLs (files with names something like "opencv.dll" or "libopencv.dll").

Comment: Though your question follows SO rules, it has quite a bad style. For example, you use links to images instead of just posting quote from error message, you don't use available formatting tools, set only a single and mostly useless tag and so on. I'm going to upvote your question to compensate downvote, but please use better wording next time. I will edit your question to show how it could look like.

Comment: Remove `D:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc10\bin` from PATH. CB uses MinGW, you don't need VC libs. I copied all libopencv*244.dll to CB/MinGW/bin, all libopencv*244.dll.a to B/MinGW/lib, and it worked. I repeat, it is not a standard way to do.

Comment: Well it does look smoother now. If i happen to ask more questions in the future I'll try to make it look better. I did what Mr. Muhammad advised and everything seems to work just fine - the project does compile and, so far, i haven't noticed any problems. I guess it's about time I start programming. Thank you very much, I wish I could upvote your comments!

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy and paste the opencv dll files to windows/system32 folder