# opencv 3.0.0 and 2.4.10 dont have MinGW folder

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, windows, opencv

I am trying to install openCV 3.0.0-beta, MinGW and eclipse. I am following steps given in [Getting started with OpenCV 2.4 and MinGW on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7) But I discover that I dont have C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\ in my opencv folder. Then I also downloaded opencv 2.4.10 but that also doesn't contain mingw folder

Answer (score 2):

It's not you, OpenCV 2.4.10 does not include MinGW build. Options are:

1. Build it yourself, using cmake files supplied with OpenCV sources and MinGW generator
2. Switch to MSVC toolchain in Eclipse