# how to compile and run opencv code from command prompt in windows 7

Tags: c++, opencv, command-line, command-prompt

I need to compile and run opencv c++ code from command prompt in windows 7. When I searched in internet I found some results for Linux but not for windows 7.

How to run the opencv code from command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the steps should be the same like described in:
[Opencv Doku](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html)

The difference is in how you invoke the compiler afterwards. For how to invoke the visualstudio compiler from command promt have look at:
[VS Building on commandline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx)

If you want to use mingw please refer to this article:
[Opencv mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7)