# How to generate .exe for opencv 3.0 c++ program from command prompt in windows10?

Tags: c++, command-prompt, windows-10, mingw32, opencv3.0

How to generate(compile) .exe for opencv 3.0 c++ program from command prompt in windows10?
Basically I wan to generte .exe file by running the scource code in command prompt.

Comment: Do you have an .exe?  If so, just type it's full path into the command window.  If not, create an .exe first.

Comment: Sorry My question was wrong. I wan to generate .exe through command prompt on windows10 platform for opencv 3.0 c++ code.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the person who wrote the code.  Barring that, you will have to look at the opencv documentation for your particular compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the compiler you are using. 
If I go on the assumption you are looking to compile with MinGW on Windows
Check out this thread for exact step by step instructions... Its for windows 7 but with updated downloads the steps should be very, very close.
[Getting started with OpenCV 2.4 and MinGW on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7)

But the exact command would be something like this...
g++ -I"C:\opencv\build\include" L"C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" loadimg.cpp -lopencv_core243 -lopencv_highgui243 -o loadimg
Replace loadimg for your files

## Edit for OpenCV 3.0

So I did a little more looking (haven't used 3.0) and it appears the most common way is to use Visual Studio - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html?highlight=build
I would recommend this approach if possible. It's the supported way and has good documentation. If you need a copy of Visual Studio - the community edition is free for up to five users. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx . Also you can use MSBUILD https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx 
to compile the program from the command line.

Alternatively, I did find some info on building the core from code using CMAKE. But it does not mention using MinGW. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#cpptutwindowsmakeown.
There does seem to be a lack of information on the this topic though.

Comment: Problem is with opencv 3.0 version there is no mingw \ lib folder in C:\opencv\build\x86...I am trying to build it using CMake but there is no proper documentation available for this on web for windows platform

Comment: It did not for opencv 3.0. I made extensive search on web still there was no documentation for opencv 3.0.