# how can i edit my opencv flags on windows?

Tags: windows, opencv, makefile

A line in the README says :

manually specify the OpenCV flags in the Makefile as following:

```
           INCS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv
           LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux -lml
```

I'm using Windows(OpenCV version 3.3.1). Can you guess what should I use instead to make it work on Windows?
Here's a link to the Makefile https://github.com/npinto/fddb-evaluation/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? 1.x?

Comment: @Silencer It's 3.3.1

Comment: You linked with `-lcxcore` for c version(1.x). I don't think it's a good practice. And If your path `/usr/local/xxx` is not suitable for windows. But I'm not familiar with `Makefile`. I think `CMake` will be a better choice.

Comment: which compiler? What are the filenames of your opencv libraries?

Comment: @Silencer Actually, I've working on the FDDB dataset. trying to run the evaluation http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/fddb/results.html the README file in that folder says:
 2. If the utility 'pkg-config' is not available for your operating system,
   edit the Makefile to manually specify the OpenCV flags from this:
      INCS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` 
      LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
   to:
      INCS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv
      LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux -lml
my system doesn't have pkg-config so I'm trying to change flags instead.

Comment: @Micka g++ compiler, I guess. I've made edits. Check them if it helps.

Comment: are the files called libhighgui.lib for example? Or libopencv_highgui331.lib?

Comment: @Micka None. They are called 'opencv_world340d.lib' or 'opencv_world340.lib' :/

Comment: are you sure those .lib files are for g++ on windows (mingw?)? According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7 the libs are called for example `libopencv_core240.dll.a` and afair you link them by omitting the "lib" prefix and the extension, so for example `-lopencv_core240` here.

Comment: @Micka I've been working with OpenCV-Python. I'm not sure how c++ works. I installed it just a few weeks back using http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Comment: if you try to compile will you get some error message like "cannot find libhighgui.lib"

Comment: I tried compiling the same code, the same way as mentioned in that question... Throwing up this error:

loadimg.cpp:1:39: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
                                       ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: @Micka Okay, I followed the steps of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7 
 and compiled again.. Getting this error now: 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_core243
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_highgui243
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: LIBS = -L/PATH_TO_LIB  -lopencv_world340.lib

Comment: @Silencer Nope,not working

Comment: This is as example on Ubuntu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/flEtZ.png